# Grails 2.5.5: Unable to access the request body of a PUT request?

Tags: grails, grails-2.0, grails-controller

I'm attempting to implement a RESTful API using Grails 2.5.5, and I'm running into a few issues.

It appears that Grails does not automatically map any methods for the corresponding HTTP methods, so I'm editing `UrlMappings.groovy`.

For example, take the following URLs:

```
GET /v1/1/persons/  <--- List of persons
POST /v1/1/persons/ <--- Create a new person
PUT /v1/1/persons/1234 <--- Edit person with ID of 1234
```

These are my url mappings:

```
"/v1/$appId/$controller/$action?/$id?(.$format)?" {
    namespace = "v1"
}

"/v1/$appId/$controller"(action: "save", method: "POST") {
    namespace = "v1"
}

"/v1/$appId/$controller/$id"(action: "update", method: "PUT") {
    namespace = "v1"
}
```

So now, the first mapping will handle the GET request in my example urls as well as other generic urls.
The second mapping will handle the second url from my example urls.
And lastly, the third mapping handles the third url from my example urls.

The issue I'm facing now is that my command object isn't getting bound properly for my PUT request. The POST request works fine however.
These are my methods:

```
def save(MyCommand cmd) {
    // works great
}  

def update(MyCommand cmd) { 
    // cmd properties are null 
    // params.id is bound though. So I'm getting the path variable.
}
```

As you can see, the logic is very simple.
But I'm completely stumped as to why I can't get the request body in the PUT method.

Additional question: How can I get the above urls to work in addition to this url?:

```
/v1/1/persons/1234/status
```

I tried the following mapping, but it does not seem to work:

```
"/v1/$appId/$controller/$id/$action" {
    namespace = "v1"
}
```

It feels like I'm stuck in this URLMappings hell!

Comment: Just a quick test... reorder your urlmappings, so the PUT mapping is first.  I think your urlmappings map some of the same URLs, so it'll just match the first one that matches.  Note that this documentation shows how you can have one line in URL mappings do ALL your mapping for GET/POST/PUT to various conventionally-named actions in your controller: https://grails.github.io/grails2-doc/2.4.4/guide/single.html#urlmappings

Comment: I have this same problem before but in Grails 3. Setting the content type of the request will bind it to your command. For me It binded when I added the **Content-Type** header and set it to **application/json** since I was passing a JSON data.